# Centering Element using jQuery Position + Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, menuitem

I have the following code below, it was modified from ([CSS-Tricks Link](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/)). It works fine, however the magic line (floating element under navigation) in my site is 40 pixels wide.

I want to permanently center align the bar (whether it falls under hover state or not), at present it is aligned left of the element. As it is using the jQuery .position() to calculate from the left, all my efforts add the 'forceRight' but negate jQuery .position().

The variable 'forceRight', finds the difference either side of the 40px bar. However I need this side gap to be enforced as the menu items are different widths.

```
var forceRight,
    off_hover_left,
    $el,
    $calcuateForceDistance,
    $magicLine_width        = 40,
    $mainNav                = $("#main-navigation"),
    $currentPosition        = $(".current-menu-item"),
    $currentPosition_width  = ($currentPosition.outerWidth() - $magicLine_width);

$mainNav.append("<span id='magic-line'></span>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .css("left", $(".current-menu-item").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left);

$("#main-navigation a").hover(function(){

    // current element
    $el                     = $(this),
    // Calcuate Distance 
    $calcuateForceDistance  = Math.floor( ( $el.outerWidth() - $magicLine_width ) / 2 );

    forceRight = ( $el.position().left + $calcuateForceDistance );


    off_hover_left = Math.floor( $currentPosition.position().left + ($currentPosition_width / 2) );

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: forceRight
    });

}, function() {

    // On Hover Out - Return to DOM LOAD (.current-menu-item)
    $magicLine.stop().animate({

        // not selected outerwidth !!! sort out variables above!
        left: off_hover_left
    });

});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: Here is an example - http://codepen.io/Ne-Ne/pen/wglBL. You can see what I mean about centering the bar on hover / load (.current-menu-item)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug in my code, I also added a doc ready to get the code to run on browser rendering. When the code loads, I also created a delay then added a class to remove the glitch (the left animation between 0 -> needed axis value.

In this case I used opacity 0, as default. and 1, on .addClass('found').

```
var forceRight,
    $el,
    $calcuateForceDistance,
    $magicLine_width        = 40,
    $mainNav                = $("#main-navigation"),
    $currentPosition        = $(".current-menu-item"),
    $currentPosition_width  = ($currentPosition.outerWidth() - $magicLine_width),
    $off_hover_left         = Math.floor( $currentPosition.position().left + ($currentPosition_width / 2) );

    // Create HTML ELEMENT
    $mainNav.append("<span id='magic-line'></span>");
    // Target -> Variable
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    // Apply attr's
    $magicLine.css("left", $(".current-menu-item").position().left);


$(document).ready(function(){

    // Enforce Code On Load
    $magicLine.stop().animate({

        // not selected outerwidth !!! sort out variables above!
        left: $off_hover_left

    }).promise().done(function(){

        // Once Positioned - Then add class (changes opacity) !
        $(this).addClass('found');

    });

    $("#main-navigation a").hover(function(){

        // current element
        $el                     = $(this),
        // Calcuate Distance 
        $calcuateForceDistance  = Math.floor( ( $el.outerWidth() - $magicLine_width ) / 2 );

        forceRight = ( $el.position().left + $calcuateForceDistance );

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: forceRight
        });

    }, function() {

        // On Hover Out - Return to DOM LOAD (.current-menu-item)
        $magicLine.stop().animate({

            // not selected outerwidth !!! sort out variables above!
            left: $off_hover_left
        });

    });
});
```

I hope this helps, someone not just me!

Answer (score -1):

In your javascript you only set the left position of your `#magic-line`. You need to set the width of the line also. Example in the code underneath (Just the rows to modify):

```
// On the initialization
$magicLine
    .css({
        "left": $(".current-menu-item").position().left,
        "width" : $(".current-menu-item").outerWidth()
    });

// On modification
$magicLine.stop().animate({
    left: leftPos,
    width: $el.outerWidth()
});
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: ISP Issues.. the width does not need to change. The calculation need attention both on load and the hover state. Your code seems to work but active changes the width of the $magicLine, which does not need to happen.

Comment: Where I did set the width of the line you also could set the left margin. You need to set this margin to the elements width divided by 2, then substract 20 (half of the lines width). Then it should be cenetered. Otherwise you can add the margin to the left position.

Comment: could you update the code above, I am sure it will click when I see it visually. many thanks